# Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap` on <div> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details,

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a material-ui package in react.js. I just want to open a drawer and close when I click anywhere on the screen.

my code is just like

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';


export default class extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
  }

  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({
      open: !this.state.open
    });
  }

  render() {
    const styles = {
      container: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        paddingTop: 200,
      },
    };

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
           <AppBar
            title="Title"
            iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
            onTouchTap={(e) => this.handleClick()}
          />
          <Drawer open={this.state.open}>
            <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
          </Drawer>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

and my Package.json file is like

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "material-ui": "latest",
    "next": "^2.1.1",
    "next-routes": "^1.0.24",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.6",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1"
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
}
```

Actually, i am using next.js with react-redux.

please suggest the best solution for this problem.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer @Mohamed Bionthman and @Turnipdabeets.

I tried to solve this problem with your suggestions but i cann't solve it.

This code is working for me.
Here i find one solution
add into current code.

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

try {
    injectTapEventPlugin()
}
catch(e) {
    //Don't do anything
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the drawer by clicking anywhere on the screen you can some sort of `onClick` event that calls your `handleToggle` function. If you want to Drawer to open when clicking on the actual Drawer you might need to add the `onRequestChange` prop to the Drawer.

Also, I wanted to point out that it's best practice to use a function in `setState` in this case instead of an object. It's not best practice to rely on this.state to calculate the next value because `setState` is an asynchronous function, so `this.state.open` might not be what you expect it to be. There's a good post you can read more about this approach [here](https://medium.com/@shopsifter/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1).

```
   handleToggle() {
    this.setState(function(prevState, props){
      return {open: !prevState.open}
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use theses properties on the Drawer

```
<Drawer
    docked={false}
    width={200}
    open={this.state.open}
    onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
 >
```

and for Warning: Unknown prop `onTouchTap`. this mean you not set the Provider. read this topic for usage of Material-UI
http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage